# connecting and inserting data into mysql database 5.5 using Python 2.7

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python, mysql-connector

Can you please help me with this issue here.

I am getting below error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bots\communication.py", line 1703, in outcommunicate
> botslib.runscript(self.userscript,self.scriptname,'outcommunicate',channeldict=self.channeldict,dbconnection=self.dbconnection,db_object=db_object)
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bots\botslib.py", line 492, in runscript
> raise ScriptError(_(u'Userscript "%(modulefile)s": "%(txt)s".'),{'modulefile':modulefile,'txt':txt})
> ScriptError: Userscript "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bots\usersys\communicationscripts\testmysqldbconnection": "Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bots\botslib.py", line 489, in runscript
> return functiontorun(**argv)
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bots\usersys\communicationscripts\testmysqldbconnection.py", line 17, in outcommunicate
> cur.execute("""INSERT INTO ccode (ccodeid,leftcode,rightcode) VALUES (%s, %s, $s)""", ( article ) )
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 159, in execute
> query = query % db.literal(args)
> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

MY code as below

```
import MySQLdb


def connect(channeldict):
    return MySQLdb.connect('localhost','XXXXXX', 'XXXXXXXXXX','test')

def outcommunicate(channeldict,dbconnection,db_object):
    cur = dbconnection.cursor()
    
    for article in db_object:
        cur.execute("""INSERT INTO ccode (ccodeid,leftcode,rightcode) 
                    VALUES (%s, %s, $s)""", 
                    ( article[0] , article[1] , article[2] ) )
        print 'in channel:', article

    # Make sure data is committed to the database
    dbconnection.commit()

    cur.close()

def disconnect(channeldict,dbconnection):
    dbconnection.close()
```

Can you please advice me

Comment: pyxthon is pold the databse os old and deprecated, why not tale the tome and upgrade. the time yoz spend debugging will be better spend upgrqading

Comment: I think there is a typo in your SQL statement. The last parameter placeholder starts with `$` (`$s`) instead of the usual `%s`. I never encountered such syntax so probably it is just a mistake.